# In Pharo, how can you measure the system's current total memory consumption?

Tags: memory, smalltalk, pharo

I'd like to track memory usage thru the runtime of my image. I'd like to frequently measure the current memory usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the Smalltalk code:

```
          Smalltalk vmParameterAt: 3
```

Comment: Aww, you ruined the fun, Mariano!

Comment: Hi, in Pharo4 this does not work anymore. If I am correct it should be `Smalltalk vm getParameters at: 3` in Pharo4.

Answer (score 4):

WorldMenu->Tools->MemoryMonitor

[image]

Comment: Unfortuantely, this is not available in Pharo4 by default.